# Report Builder cannot publish to report server

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2012, linux, ssrs-2012

This is currently in a cloud lab environment. We're not allowed to join any AD domains.

We have a linux server (RHEL 6) running MySQL 5.3 and a Windows SQL Server 2012 on Win 2k8 R2.

Our laptop is Win 7 64bit running Report Builder 3.0. We created an OBDC connection to the MySQL database and are able to build reports in Report Builder. However, if we add the connection to the report server (http:// IP_ADDRESS/reportserver) it gives us the following error when trying to publish:

> For more information about this error navigate to the report server on
>   the local server machine, or enable remote errors.
>
> Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
>
> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

I am able to open SQL Management Studio locally on my laptop and connect to the remote SQL server without issue.

Comment: Have you published DataSource1 too?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic since this is 4 years old and likely has little use to others unless OP decides to come back and provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is "DataSource1"? You need to make sure that the datasource for the report you're executing is configured correctly. Here is some info for that: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159736.aspx

Comment: DataSource1 is the connection to the MySQL Database. In Report Builder, I click 'New Dataset'. I choose the ODBC, enter the MySQL connection string (user/pass). Then test the connection, and click 'Ok'.

Comment: Have you created the ODBC connection on the server you are deploying to?